# How to fix this warning 'var' used instead of 'let' or 'const' JsLint in phpStrom?

Tags: phpstorm, jslint

I want to fix this in the code file not in jslint setting options. The JS file is in PHP project. How can I remove the warning from here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open PhpStorm Settings
-> Languages & Framework 
-> Javascript
 and in "JavaScript language version" dropdown select EcmaScript 5

Comment: thats great.Its work EcmaScript 6 for type script and EcmaScript 5 for javascript.Please edit and add EcmaScript 5 there.I have changed from 6 to 5

Comment: I just want to suppress it for the Google Analytics snippet, not for everything. I'm looking for the a suppress constant like `<!--suppress CommaExpressionJS, CheckValidXmlInScriptTagBody -->`

Answer (score 3):

in Settings , find Inspections tab .
Then find the one denoted in picture below (which is "'var' used instead of 'let' or 'const'", and change the severity to no highlighting.

[image]

The squiggling line disappears after you apply this new setting.

Answer (score 2):

When using **multiple versions of JavaScript language** in your project, you can also set specific JavaScript language version for each directory (e.g. when you're using ECMAScript 5.1 in views in `<script>` tag, but assets are written in ECMAScript 6+)...

[image]